# Removing sublist from nested lists based on element values

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying to remove sublist from nested lists based on elements values.

```
data = [['1', 'i like you'],
['2', 'you are bad'],
['5', 'she is good'],
['7', 'he is poor']]

negative_words = set(['poor', 'bad'])
```

If the second column contains negative words, I would like to remove the sub-lists. So, the desired results are below. Any suggestions?

```
data = [['1', 'i like you'],
['5', 'she is good']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can readily think of two ways.

```
>>> data = [['1', 'i like you'], ['2', 'you are bad'],
            ['5', 'she is good'], ['7', 'he is poor']]
>>> neg_words = {'poor', 'bad'}
```

Use convert string in the sublist to a set, and then check if it is [`disjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) with `neg_words`, like this

```
>>> [[n, ws] for n, ws in data if set(ws.split()).isdisjoint(neg_words)]
[['1', 'i like you'], ['5', 'she is good']]
```

Or simply check if none of words from the string in the list, is in `neg_words`, like this

```
>>> [[n, ws] for n, ws in data if all(w not in neg_words for w in ws.split())]
[['1', 'i like you'], ['5', 'she is good']]
```